# jquery and css hint needed $("elemet").css();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to move the shape 200px  down using `$("#shape").css("top","200px");`
and it does not work, any advice?

```
> <style type="text/css">
>         #shape{
>             width: 200px;
>             height: 200px;
>             background-color: red;
>             display: none;
>             position: :relative;
>             
>         }
>     
>     </style>
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //var start=new Date().getTime();

    function appear(){
        $("#shape").css("top","200px");
        $("#shape").css("display","block");
        start=new Date().getTime();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You have to use that in conjunction with `position:` For example: `$("#shape").css({"position":"relative","top":"200px"});`

Comment: i have a Style already  ... <style type="text/css">
        #shape{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            
            position: :relative;
            
        }

Comment: Please edit your question to show the css code.

Comment: Maybe the 2 colons are hurting you: `position: :relative;` should be `position: relative;`

Comment: i put the style sheet now sorry iam new , 
its a small project for reaction time so a square appear and disappear . i just want it to be down by using this formula ..$("#shape").css.("top","200px") is it possible ?

Comment: thank  you dude for your time much appreciated , yes 2 colons were the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>your title</title>
</head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  #shape{ width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red; display: none; 
  position:relative;

 }

</style>
<body>
  <div id="shape"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function appear(){
    $("#shape").css("top","200px");
    $("#shape").css("display","block");
    start=new Date().getTime();
 }
appear()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```